# How findQuery works in Ember local storage adapter

Tags: ember.js

In the `findQuery` function of the Ember local storage adapter, I'm confused about [this line](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/blob/master/localstorage_adapter.js#L94) containing `"[Object RegExp]"`. What does it mean?

```
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(test) == '[object RegExp]') {
      push = test.test(record[property]);
    } else {
      push = record[property] === test;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Object RegExp]` is the string representation (`toString()`) of a [regular expression object in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

That part of the code checks if the query is a regular expression. If so, it runs the expression object's `test()` on the property, otherwise does a strict `===` comparison.

Try running this in a console:

```
var test = /a.*?nice regex/;
var string = "Is this a very nice regex?";
console.log( Object.prototype.toString.call(test) );
console.log( test.test(string) );
```

Comment: See it in action in this [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/360/edit). There I apply `App.Model.find({attribute: /StringToSearch/i})`, where the `i` is for case insensitivity.